Does it make sense to take a formal power series over a non-ring?
Suppose we have the set of nonnegative integers. This is obviously not a ring, and not even a group. But are we able to identify ring-like properties for it if we take a formal power series over it?
For example, are we able to take a formal power series $f(x)$
with nonnegative integer coefficients and identify properties such as a multiplicative inverse or irreducibility/nonirreducibility?

If $R$ is a semiring (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring), I believe you can define the semirings of polynomials $R[x]$ and formal power series $R[[x]]$ with coefficients in $R$ as usual. There will almost never be mutliplicative inverses of elements in these semirings though.

https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-6264-0

would these work similar to $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$?

The formal power series $2$ has no multiplicative inverse in your structure.

are we able to factor in a similar nature? like can we have irreducible or nonirreducible elements or elements which have infinite factors
